# How to make table row Dynamic in Material ui React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design, mern

I want to create the dynamic table like this and My code works perfectly when I add the data to max and min capacity for the first time,
[image]

but the problem is, when I am trying to add for further times then Another time max and min field creates
[image]

Here is my code of Table head,

```
   <TableHead style={{ textAlign: 'justify' }}>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell align="center" rowSpan={2}>Start Date</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center" rowSpan={2}>End Date</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center" rowSpan={2}>Recurrence</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center" rowSpan={2}>Price Type</TableCell>
                    <TableCell colSpan={6} align="center">Configuration</TableCell>
                    <TableCell sx={{ pr: 2 }} align="center" rowSpan={2}>Price</TableCell>
                    <TableCell sx={{ pr: 3 }} align="center" rowSpan={2}>Action</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell align="center">Min Person</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">Max Person</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">Min Hours</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="center">Max Hours</TableCell>

                    {tableData.map((data) => data.state?.maxCapacity>0 &&
                        <>
                            <TableCell align="center">Min Capacity</TableCell>
                        </>
                        
                    )}
                    {tableData.map((data) => data.state?.minCapacity>0 &&
                        <>
                            <TableCell align="center">Max Capacity</TableCell>
                        </>
                        
                    )}

                </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
```

And Table body:

```
 <TableCell align="center">
                            {data.state?.priceType === 2 || data.state?.minCapacity> 0 ? data.state?.min : '- -'}
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="center">
                            {data.state?.priceType === 2 || data.state?.maxCapacity> 0 ? data.state?.max : '- -'}
                        </TableCell>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you mean, the second time you add data to the `Max/Min Capacity` column, new column of those two gets created again? What exactly is the issue?

Comment: Yes,exactly that is the issue